# My external USB HDD doesnt spin down

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive

I have a raspberry pi running with raspbmc.
There is connected a WD Elements ( /dev/sda1 ).

Unfortunately the disk doesn't spin down.
It looks like hdparm is not working.

The following I have tried:

```
sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 issuing standby command
```

I tested it with

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 drive state is:  standby
```

looks like it spinned down and turned into standby.

The problem is, it doesn't go in standby by itself.
Even with

```
sudo hdparm -S 5
```

it doesnt spin down after 25 seconds.

Thanks so far.

Comment: Did you specify the drive for that last command: `sudo hdparm -S 5 /dev/sda` ?